# deleting an object in Bluej

Tags: java, bluej

I'm making an project according to the movie The Ghost and The Darkness, I have created an object of human class and 2 objects of lion class by GUI.

```
public class Lion{
     private String Name;

     public Lion(String Name){
        this.Name=Name;
     }
}
```

this is Human class,

```
 public class Human{
       private String name;

       public Human(String name){
           name="Hunter";
       }
}
```

Now, I want to make an object of hunt that will kill/delete the objects of Lion.

Comment: You haven't created any objects yet in that code.  You've only created some classes.  There are no objects to delete.

Comment: Also, what's your question?  So far, you're just telling us a story about something you want to do.

Comment: I know that already mentioned above.

Comment: My story is my question I want to know about?

Comment: If you know that already, then why are you talking about deleting objects?  You can't delete an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: No, there is no question in your story.

Comment: For one thing, questions have question marks.  The previous sentence is not a question.  What is your question?  The previous sentence is a question.

Comment: @MinhajShafqat Take a look at my solution below. ***Do let me know*** whether it solves your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create something similar to a game where characters can be killed (or removed from game).

There are at least 2 ways you can go about doing it:

```
//You can plan the hierarchy for your classes first..
//This is optional, but to make it interesting, we create a super class

abstract class LivingThings
{
    private Boolean isAlive;
    private String name;

    public LivingThings(String name){
        this.name = name;
        isAlive = true;    //When an object is created, set it to alive
    }
    public void setAlive(Boolean flag){
        this.isAlive = flag;
    }
}
```

**1. Flagging it as dead**

Now you Human and Lion can be a subclass of LivingThings and all sub-classes will posses a property known as `isAlive`:

```
class Lion extends LivingThings{
    //Your other properties for Lion
}

class Human extends LivingThings{
    //Your other properties for Human

    public void kill(LivingThings target){
        target.setAlive(false);    //Kill an object (but object still exist in game)
    }
}
```

If you are making a game, very often you do not need to remove the object from the game immediately Is was killed. But instead, we flag is as "dead".

**2. Deference the object (not recommended)**

If you really want to remove it. You can do it as such:

```
public void kill(LivingThings target){
    target = null;    //Remove object (Wait for Garbage Collector to collect it) 
}
```

However, by setting it to `null` may cause undesirable consequences as other parts of your program may still be referencing to that object, hence giving you `NullPointerException`.